# How do I rotate an image on my server then save it back to to its initial url?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, file-upload, rotation

My goal here is to be able to pull an image out of a url on my server, rotate that image by 90 degrees, then save it back to the same url I pulled it from.

I have tried many different methods of this but nothing is working.

This is what I have currently:

```
$imurl = "../images/sample.jpg";
$file = fopen($imurl, "rb");        
$rotim = imagerotate($file, 90, 0);     
move_uploaded_file($rotim, $imurl);
```

I am not sure if this changes anything but the pictures url is not in the same directory as the current file.

I have been alternating between these two link formats - neither seem to work.

```
$imurl = "https://www.site.com/images/1/picture.jpg"

$imurl = "../images/1/picture"
```

Comment: syntax error. missing quotes. also, you are not using a url, but a directory (path)

Comment: It's still got the file handle open you have to fclose it too.

Comment: and you dont want move_uploaded_file

Comment: could you please post the correct code for something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your 90% there..

```
$imurl = "../images/sample.jpg";
$file = imagecreatefromjpeg($imurl); //http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
$rotim = imagerotate($file, 90, 0);   //http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php      
imagejpeg($rotim, $imurl); //http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php
```

be careful with relative paths, i prefer to use the full path where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I put this code in it returns me three errors:
1. imagecreatefromjpeg -> failed to open stream
2. imagerotate -> expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
3. imagejpeg -> expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: all relate to the first one, the image is not where you say it is

Comment: I changed the url to all the types that it could possibly be and it is still not working, same errors

Comment: if your using a url you need the fopen wrappers enabled, but the above is not a url but a file path, so i'm not sure what your doing. how about putting the file in the same directory as the script and use `$imurl = "sample.jpg";`

Comment: wow I'm stupid, figured out that the path I was using was flawed.  THANK YOU - this works perfectly and is much appreciated